# Difficulty accessing nested values in TOML

Tags: json, toml, wrangler

I'm trying to adapt an Express app to CloudFlare Functions. As I understand it, Functions/serverless doesn't really support anything that needs to read from a file system. And so the advice apparently is to subsume my config values into my `wrangler.toml` file.

Here's my JSON:

```
{
  "zero": "etc",
  "one": {
    "two": {
      "three": "four"
    }
  }
}
```

[This JSON-to-TOML util](https://transform.tools/json-to-toml) gave me:

```
zero = "etc"

[one.two]
three = "four"
```

I put that into my `wrangler.toml` right under the `[vars]` section heading and start the server, which it tells me:

```
Your worker has access to the following bindings:
- Vars:
  - zero: "etc"
```

Why aren't my nested values coming through?

Comment: Because those are in a different section.  All the server sees are things in the `[vars]` section.  Everything else is ignored.

Comment: Oh, OK. So is there a way I can pump in nested values or would they have to be a flat list?

Comment: Also added context info.

Comment: I guess I could add my JSON as a stringified var value and parse it within the app, but that seems horrible.

Comment: You could use names like `one.two.three`.

Comment: Ah OK, that's going to be a very un-fun half an hour to do that conversion manually (the convertors do it the way I showed in my post). If that's the only answer, feel free to post it up as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

> that's going to be a very un-fun half an hour to do that conversion manually

You could use the command-line tool `tomlq` from [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) to automate the JSON-to-TOML conversion. A provided filter is run internally using [jqlang/jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq), so any kind of transformation can be applied to it on the fly. For example, given your JSON sample as `input.json`, to wrap everything below `[vars]` you can run:

```bash
tomlq -n -t '{vars: $j[]}' --slurpfile j input.json
```

```ini
[vars]
zero = "etc"

[vars.one.two]
three = "four"
```